# VISJS: Changing the distance on how far nodes are spaced out

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

I am using vis.js network to display nodes on a graph however I am interested in changing on how the spacing is displayed. When a node is clicked, it's neighbors are displayed.

I noticed that when there are already a lot of nodes and more is to be displayed, the spacing gets huge. How can I reduce the spacing? When I turn on physics, gravity brings it closer but I prefer gravity to be off.
[image]

Comment: please add a [mcve]

Comment: you can set edge lengths to small values

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find the solution to this?